# Exporting data with selected graphs in PHP good coding

Tags: php, architecture

I have a page where the user can select a date range and around 40 checkboxes (checked by default). Each checkbox represents data that I capture and allow them to export. I want the checked checkboxes to be exported to my Excel file.

All the graphs I want to export are passed through via this variable in $_POST:

```
array (size=3)
  'from' => string '2019-01-24' (length=10)
  'to' => string '2019-02-24' (length=10)
  'graphs' => 
    array (size=5)
      'matches-graphs' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'amount_contact_per_day_org_vol' (length=30)
          1 => string 'amount_total_matches' (length=20)
          2 => string 'amount_clicks_phone' (length=19)
      'volunteers-graphs' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'amount_new_volunteers' (length=21)
          1 => string 'amount_volunteers' (length=17)
          2 => string 'amount_findable_volunteers' (length=26)
      'vacancies-graphs' => 
        array (size=6)
          0 => string 'amount_new_vacancies' (length=20)
          1 => string 'amount_active_vacancies' (length=23)
          2 => string 'amount_expired_vacancies' (length=24)
          3 => string 'amount_archived_vacancies' (length=25)
          4 => string 'amount_active_vacancies_per_interest' (length=36)
          5 => string 'vacancies_list_org' (length=18)
      'traffic-graphs' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => string 'amount_views_per_vol_profile' (length=28)
          1 => string 'amount_views_per_vacancy' (length=24)
          2 => string 'amount_views_per_org_profile' (length=28)
          3 => string 'amount_logins_volunteers' (length=24)
          4 => string 'amount_logins_orgs' (length=18)
      'filters-graphs' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'filters_used_search_vol' (length=23)
          1 => string 'filters_used_search_org' (length=23)
          2 => string 'filters_used_search_vac' (length=23)
```

I then pass this $graphs array to a function where I want to export the graphs specified Excel. I am using phpoffice/phpspreadsheet library for this.

I want to pass through this array and for each item in there I want to write to the Excel file.

I was thinking with the following code, but there has to be a better way?

```
if (!empty($graphs)) {
        if (!empty($graphs['matches-graphs'])) {
            foreach ($graphs['matches-graphs'] as $graph) {
                if ($graph == 'amount_contact_per_day_org_vol') {
                    //Export data
                }
                if ($graph == 'amount_total_matches') {
                    //Export data
                }
                if ($graph == 'amount_clicks_phone') {
                    //Export data
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($graphs['volunteers-graphs'])) {
            foreach ($graphs['volunteers-graphs'] as $graph) {
                if ($graph == 'amount_new_volunteers') {
                    //Export data
                }
                if ($graph == 'amount_volunteers') {
                    //Export data
                }
                if ($graph == 'amount_findable_volunteers') {
                    //Export data
                }
            }
        }
        //etc for all categories
    }
```

Comment: So every kind of graph data has different keys?

Comment: Rough percentage, i'd say, 70% of the graphs have different keys, but some of the graphs have the same !

Comment: So, you will need to have an associative array with all the mappings. Then, you can just loop through and seek those keys for a particular kind of graph data and loop through. Note that this only applies if the logic for `//Export data` remains the same.